# Update form input before submit

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

I'm developing JSF web application and have some HOW-TO questions.
I have the following use-case scenario:

1. User types text, using h:inputText
2. then clicks submit
3. Value from above h:inputText is encrypted on the client side (using JavaScript)
4. Form is submitted with encrypted value
5. h:inputText value is restored to previous value (typed by user, not encrypted).

I would like to send encrypted values in generic way. It should be transparent for user. I would like to have a mechanism to mark "encrypt-ready" fields using html attribute eg. encrypt="true".

Data have to be encrypted on the client side because server can't see it in RAW form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a good idea to set non–standard attributes. Consider a [*data-** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead like `"data-encrypt=true"`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this JS encryption? If you are trying to secure the data you should host this on an HTTPS site instead and not worry about that

Comment: @zaph thanks - question edited.

Comment: `server can't see it in RAW form` Do you have some specific reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how it could work with jQuery:

```
<h:head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <script>
        $(function() {

            $("form").submit(function() {
                $("input[data-encrypt='true']").each(function() {
                    $(this).val(encrypt($(this).val()));
                });
            });

            $("input[data-encrypt='true']").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $(this).val(decrypt($(this).val()));
                }
            });
        });

        function decrypt(str) {
            // to be implemented
            return "decrypted value";
        }

        function encrypt(str) {
            // to be implemented
            return "encrypted value";
        }
    </script>


    <h:form id="form">
        <h:inputText value="#{viewBean.value}" id="val" pt:data-encrypt="true" />
        <h:commandButton value="Process" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

You could extract the javascript part in an own .js file and include it in any page you need.
Don't forget to define pt namespace:

```
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

This solution is not working with f:ajax.

Comment: thank you very much for solution! :) I wonder how to deal with ajax="true" for primefaces or f:ajax. I think about similar function like yours but executed in "onclick" in p:commandLink or h:commandButton (with f:ajax).

Comment: Yes, for encryption you can work with onclick on the button and for decrypt you can work with onevent (for f:ajax) or with oncomplete (for p:commandButton). I've tried to use onstart for p:commandButton instead of onclick for encryption, but it didn't work. The raw value was submitted instead of the encrypted one.